# React development server keep disconnecting and page gets refreshed on every disconnect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

The server gets disconnect after every 4-5 secs which causes page refresh and especially on the very first render it happens multiple times.

The console has this message

```
The development server has disconnected.
Refresh the page if necessary.
```

Here's my webpackDevServer.config.js

```
 module.exports = function(proxy, allowedHost) {
 return {
 disableHostCheck: !proxy ||
  process.env.DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK === 'true',
 compress: true,
 clientLogLevel: 'none',
 contentBase: paths.appPublic,
 watchContentBase: true,
 publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
 quiet: true,
 watchOptions: {
   ignored: /node_modules/,
 },
 https: protocol === 'https',
 host: host,
 overlay: false,
 historyApiFallback: {
   disableDotRule: true,
 },
 public: allowedHost,
 proxy,
 setup(app) {
   app.use(errorOverlayMiddleware());
   app.use(noopServiceWorkerMiddleware());
    },
   };
 };
```

It's very annoying that either I want to stop the live reload at all or get rid of this issue.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having this exact issue on mac, even when trying the default `my-app` created by following the docs.

Answer (score 2):

Recently, I've had this issue after updating react-scripts to the latest version, 3.3.0. I simply went into my `package.json` and updated `"react-scripts": "3.3.0"` to `"react-scripts" : "3.2.0"`

After that:

```
npm install
npm start
```

And I no longer saw this issue.